# Kaspersky blocking server's ip address

Tags: windows-server-2012, anti-virus

I am consistently getting the error that TCP from "server ip" to local port 135 Denied: Intrusion.Win.DCOM.exploit within the kaspersky small office security suite and this disconnects my users computer from the server to they dont have access to the shared drives. Not sure how to go about fixing this any advice would be appreciated.  My current work around is disabling the network attack blocker

Answer (score 2):

You. Have. A. Virus. Yeahahh..

Now, using google is not stupid. "Intrusion.Win.DCOM.exploit" directy me first hit to:

http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t15616.html

which is btw. where I would ask this first.

"Although it is generally a good idea to be updated with your patches, this alone will not help. Read here and apply Windows Worms Doors Cleaner".

Oh, that looks like you have a worm in your network, and Kapersky just does it's job.

Sadly the link to cleaning is down, so - you will have some work finding a way to handle this.

Note: I also find references saying this is a bug, in which case you will have to take this up with - Kapersky. Not sure at the moment.... I would start running a full virus scan on the machines that supposedly start the attack.